# Scaling music-driven LED box?

Tags: led-strip, music

I am trying to replicate http://www.instructables.com/id/Music-LED-Light-Box/ .  But instead of using 6 LEDs, I want to go with >150 LEDs (also, using a LED strip instead of the individual LEDs), how can I make this circuit scale? Do I just append more LEDs or does it get waaaay more complicated? Is it different to add the LED strip rather than soldering LED by LED, manually?

The best thing about this circuit was its simplicity, and I'm trying to keep it.

**edit:** the initial circuit diagram is in the [step 6 of the original instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Music-LED-Light-Box/step6/Building-the-circuit/)

[image]

Comment: This foolish circuit is potentially bad for your audio amplifier. When the TIP31 transistor turns on, it has a low impedance to ground, quite likely lower than what the amplifier expects to drive. In particular, if you want to use a headphone amplifier, there should be a base resistor of at least several hundred ohms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note, the original solution is a horrible way to get music reactive lights.**

But I will still answer it.

Use a small transistor with better gain, to drive the low gain but high current TIP31. Allows a smaller current from the audio, but requires a higher voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOYWXS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Might not work, if the audio signal can't provide a 0.65 + 1.8v drop across the small transistor vbe and tip31 vbe. Still has a risk of blowing the speaker driver, but less than the original. I hope you don't care about your ipod or computer output too much.

Only provides a single channel. If you use one on both Right and Left audio, you can get two colors.

**Better Way**

Use an opamp to boost and split the audio:
[image]

Use one output to go to the speakers, and use the other two for your led driving transistor. Duplicate for both left and right audio. Leave out the 50 uf capacitor for the led outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The existing circuit isn't very good; there is no provision to limit the current through the LEDs, so it's very easy to burn out the LEDs. The circuit as-designed should be modified to put a resistor in-line with the LEDs.

However, if you want to use an LED strip, those typically have built-in resistors and it's quite easy to find 12V versions. Using an LED strip, the circuit *should* work; note that the tip31 can only handle 3 amps of current and some of the LED strips pull quite a bit of current. Check the current draw on the strip.

It's also possible that the Tip31 will need a small heatsink on it to stay cool.

Comment: It also has no provision to limit the current through the output stage of the amplifier, whenever the TIP31 turns on.